# Woocommerce force update database stucked

Tags: woocommerce

After we upgraded woocommerce to the latest version (3.4.4), the message keeps appearing

“WooCommerce data update – Your database is being updated in the background. Taking a while? Click here to run it now.”

When we clicked on the ‘Click here to run it now’, it shows a HTTP 500 error and when we reload the page, it shows the woocommerce general setting page.

I looked at the debug report and its says:

"
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function remove_cap() on null in /home/artgrain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-update-functions.php on line 1367
"

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue? I have someone told me it is my theme outdated but when I deactivated all plugins and theme to install twenty-seventeen only, this error still persists.

I appreciate your help, thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like the `shop_manager` role hasn't been created properly. Try uninstalling and then reinstalling WooCommerce.

Comment: Hi bfl, thank you for your help but the issue still persist after I uninstall, delete then install and activate back woocommerce...

Comment: WooCommerce 3.4.4 includes an update routine that recreates roles. Because of this, I think it would be OK to just skip this problematic routine by commenting out the line of code mentioned in the error message. I would recommend backing up your website before try this.